# How can I get am overlaying png to hide when clicked and not show again?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML page within an app which has a PNG image displaying instructions which is overlaying the content when the user first opens the page. I am using jquery to hide the PNG image when clicked and this all works fine. However every time the user exits the page and re-enteres it, the PNG always appears. Is there a way I can set it so that once it has been clicked once it never shoes again until the app is shutdown and restarted? I currently have the jquery in the head of my HTML page. Any help would be much appreciated as I am a little bit out of my depth, I have seen similar layouts working on other apps but not sure if it is using HTML and jquery. My HTML code is:

HTML:

```
<script>    

$(document).ready(function() {
    var overlay = $('#overlay');
    overlay.on('click', function (e) {
        overlay
            .hide()
            .off();
    });
});

</script>

<body>

<div id="overlay">
   <img src="InstructionsV15.png" height="475" width="300"/>
</div>

</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any help or advice.

Comment: you would need to do some caching.

Comment: Use cookies or preferably a session to hold the information. Here is pretty much everything you could need to use cookies with javascript. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp . There is a lightweight jQuery plugin for cookies as well: https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie. Sessions on the other hand need to be provided by the server technology, which might not be applicable, depending on what you mean by 'app'.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) to store the information